# quip development console

Tags: quip, liveapps

Hi I would like to develop for Quip. I am following along https://quip.com/dev/liveapps. One of the first steps is to access the development console within Quip, located at
https://quip.com/dev/console/
Now my company has an enterprise contract with Quip, my URL after logging in is 
https://quip-name-of-mycompany.com
The respective link
https://quip-name-of-mycompany.com/dev/console/
does not work. Is there a way to access the console? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are signed into your quip account in your browser, you can simply go to quip.com/dev/console and it should take you to your development console. Alternatively, you can go to quip.com/dev and select "Console" from the menu bar in the upper-right. If you are signed in you will be taken to your console, otherwise you will be prompted to login to your account.